# How to redirect from bucket root to subdirectory in AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, redirect, url-rewriting

I have an amazon S3 bucket serving a website from `S3bucketurl.com/foo/index.html`.

I would like to configure a [redirection rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html), that automatically rewrite the URL as follows:

Accessing `S3bucketurl.com` should automatically redirect to `S3bucketurl.com/foo`, and serve the `index.html` file contained in the subfolder `foo`.

I tried to set up the Redirection Rule as such:

```xml
<RoutingRules>
  <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
      <KeyPrefixEquals>/</KeyPrefixEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <ReplaceKeyWith>api</ReplaceKeyWith>
    </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

which results in a `404`:

```
404 Not Found

Code: NoSuchKey
Message: The specified key does not exist.
Key: index.html
```

I've also tried permutations of `<ReplaceKeyWith>/api</ReplaceKeyWith>`, `<ReplaceKeyWith>api/</ReplaceKeyWith>` and `<ReplaceKeyWith>/api/</ReplaceKeyWith>` to no avail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> `<KeyPrefixEquals>/</KeyPrefixEquals>`

There are two problems, here: first, this matches a *prefix*, meaning there's an implicit `*` at the end.  Thst isn't what you want, here.  Also no key in an S3 bucket typically has a prefix of `/`.  The object key starts with the character after the leading slash.  Your `<ReplaceKeyWith>` is ignored because the prefix test never matches.  But rules are not the best solution, here.

The way to do what you want is this:

Upload an empty file to create a new object in the root of the bucket, named whatever name you use for your index documents, typically `index.html`.  Make it public unless your bucket policy makes everything public.

In the object metadata for this object, set `x-amz-website-redirect-location` to `/api/` (or `/foo/`, or whatever path you intend).

Comment: Thank you, this is actually the solution I came up with myself. Great to see this approach confirmed. :)